# Laravel: query with a different where condition in a different row

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a classrooms table with a "quota" column that has different values. In one class, there are many students. How to display classrooms data with `where` condition which total students per `row < "quota"` ? Here's the table : [image: table].

Code :

```
Classroom::with('subject.teacher')->with('students')->whereHas('subject', fn ($query) => $query->where('grade', $grade))->withCount('students')->having('students_count', '<', 'quota');
```

when I use this code the result is empty

when "having" is removed this is the result :
[image: result]

The desired result only displays 3 classroom

Comment: it gives an error result "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'students' in 'having clause' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `withCount` function appends an additional select column to your query. It does not use `GROUP BY` which is typically what is used in conjunction with `having`.

You can't actually filter by subqueries that are added in the select. However fortunately Laravel allows you to select rows based on how many related models they have using `has`. This query is also added as a subquery, but within the where clauses so you can also use column names within it like below:

```
Classroom::with('subject.teacher')
    ->with('students')
    ->whereHas('subject', fn ($query) => $query->where('grade', $grade))
    ->has('students', '<', \DB::raw('quota')) 
    ->withCount('students');
```

Comment: it gives an error result "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'students_count' in 'where clause'"

Comment: @php sorry my mistake. I've updated it now

Comment: yes this is the complete query, thank you @apokryfos

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`has`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) and a `DB::raw`.

```php
// Simplified version
Classroom::has('students', '<=', DB::raw('classrooms.quota'))->get();
```